# Listing SSH Tunnels

Tags: ssh

Can You help me with finding out how to list 'available' ssh tunnels ?
I will describe what I mean:

I have two hosts 'Client' and 'Server'. Now Client create SSH connection using command:

```
ssh -v -L4000:127.0.0.1:4001 server
```

SSH client receives confirmation:

```
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:4000 forwarded to remote address 127.0.0.1:4001
```

So tunnel is setup although client does not used it yet.
From server side, how can I check that such 'tunnel' was opened ?

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -v -L4000:127.0.0.1:4001 server
```

When you run this command, the `ssh` program will listen on port 4000 for TCP connections. It doesn't immediately notify the remote server that any kind of tunneling arrangement is in place.

When the ssh program receives a connection on port 4000, it will send a "[direct-tcpip](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#section-7.2)" message to the remote SSH server, specifying 127.0.0.1 port 4001 as the target of the tunnel. At that time, the remote SSH server could log the request or perform some other kind of notification.

The OpenSSH `sshd` program looks like it logs a debug-level message when a direct-tcpip message is received. You would only see the message if you have debug output enabled. If `sshd` is configured to refuse port forward requests, it will refuse the tunnel request and log a message that it has done so.